# How to highlight a parent list item without highlighting children list items?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, nested-lists

I'm having trouble with a link list I'm generating using Wordpress, which displays a specific page link as well as all of its children pages links. I'm trying to have the links become highlighted when you hover over them, and then when you click on them and navigate to the page, that page's link stays highlighted. I have found a way to mostly achieve this using:

```
#sidebar a:hover{
    padding: 7px;
    background-color: #f7f9fe;
    color: #728186;
}
#sidebar ul > li .current_page_item{
    padding: 7px;
    background-color: #f7f9fe;
    color: #728186;
}
```

but that doesn't allow me to highlight the parent page/li. If I use:

```
#sidebar li.current_page_item
```

the child stays highlighted on its page, but on the parent page it also highlights the child item, not just itself.

here's my parsed php:

```
<ul id="sidebar" class="sidelist">
    <li class="pagenav"><h5>WHAT WE DO</h5>
        <ul>
            <li class="page_item page-item-39 current_page_item"><a href="http://www.autismrecoveryfoundation.org/meet-the-board" title="Meet the Board">Meet the Board</a>
            <ul class='children'>
                <li class="page_item page-item-84"><a href="http://www.autismrecoveryfoundation.org/meet-the-board/being-a-board-member-101" title="Being A Board Member 101">Being A Board Member 101</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

Here is the template tag I'm using from the Wordpress page about wp list pages (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages):

```
<?php 
            // use wp_list_pages to display parent and all child pages all generations (a tree with parent)
            $parent = 39;
            $args=array(
             'title_li' => '',
             'child_of' => $parent
            );
            $pages = get_pages($args);  
            if ($pages) {
              $pageids = array();
              foreach ($pages as $page) {
                $pageids[]= $page->ID;
              }

              $args=array(
                'title_li' => '<h5>WHAT WE DO</h5>',
                'include' =>  $parent . ',' . implode(",", $pageids)
              );
              wp_list_pages($args);
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

To display your list of pages in a flat list, set `depth` to -1:

```
$args=array(
  'depth' => -1,
  'title_li' => '<h5>WHAT WE DO</h5>',
  'include' =>  $parent . ',' . implode(",", $pageids)
);
```

That way you won't have to mess around with child selectors, and your subpages won't be contained in your main page's `li` anymore.

---

**Old answer**

The problem lies in this selector:

```
#sidebar ul > li .current_page_item
```

The `#sidebar ul` part is looking for `ul` which descends from `#sidebar`, but in your code `ul` *is* the `#sidebar`. Also, `li .current_page_item` would find *any* `.current_page_item` inside the `li` that contains your heading.

Change your selector to this:

```
#sidebar > li > ul > .current_page_item
```

You can also use this, since your pages widget has its own class anyway:

```
.pagenav > ul > .current_page_item
```

Comment: thanks for helping! so I tried both of your suggestions, as well as the 2 from before you had edited the post, and none of them are doing it. I tried using #sidebar > li > ul > .current_page_item, and it when on the parent page keeps both parent and child highlighted, and then when on the child page, neither is highlighted. Would you mind taking a look at the page? http://www.autismrecoveryfoundation.org/meet-the-board

Comment: @Amanda: Can you show me your WordPress template tag for this navigation list? Or is it in a widget?

Comment: @BoltClock: I've edited the post to show the template tag. I wish I knew how to just make the list only be one level, because that would solve the problem, so there weren't any nested lists to deal with.

Comment: @Amanda: No problem. Be sure to click the checkmark to mark an answer as accepted. Glad I helped! :)